# Derivative of a function

Tags: calculus

Which is the derivative of $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x)=x^c, c \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

Is the same as in the case where $ c \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Yes, it is the same rule.

Comment: How do you define this function? Say for $c = -\pi, x = -1$?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same with the exception that the domain of the function is $\mathbb{R}+$ as non-integer power of negative values are not well defined.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents_with_negative_bases